# MPMusicPlayerController not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to start playing music from within my application. I have iOs 6 but I need it to run in 5.1 as I need to support iPad 1 which goes up to that version.

I imported both CoreMedia and MediaPlayer frameworks and I am playing via the MPMusicPlayerController. I am able to get the list of songs, but playing doesn't work. I am testing in a real device, not the simulator.

Any thoughts into what is wrong?

```
__strong NSArray * _myMusic;
__strong MPMusicPlayerController * _player;
// Specify a media query
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
// Obtain the media item collections from the query
_myMusic = [query collections];
_player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]; //also tried iPodMusicPlayer
MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:_myMusic];
[_player setQueueWithItemCollection:currentQueue];
[_player setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
[_player setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
[_player setVolume:1];
[_player play];
```

Comment: Are you catching the PlaybackStateDidChange and NowPlayingItemDidChange notifications from your MPMusicPlayerController? easier to debug that way.

Comment: Not sure about here, but in AVAudioPlayer you can't link to online files. It has to be local. Where do you get the songs from here?

Comment: I am getting the songs from my iPad's songs. It brings them correctly.

Comment: I am not catching the notifications. I will do that. Thanks for the help.